# How to Execute two different sessions of different databse of sql under single transaction scope using NHibernate

Tags: sql, entity-framework, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

My requirement are - I have use two different database of SQL for insert,update,delete operation and I want take this two different session under one transaction, because any exception occur then rollback both database table data.
So how to resolve this problem using NHibernate.
Can Nhibernate give such type of facility.
And also any Idea to read two connection string using hibernate.cfg config file.

> For example:
>
> Session s1; -- db1
>
> Session s2; -- db2
>
> s1.Save(obj);
>
> s2.Update(obj);

so take the above two operation in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own [connection](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-userjdbc). So each session could be given a connection to a different database. Whether those connections would be enlisted in the ambient `TransactionScope` is something you would have to experiment with. If you enable sufficient logging, you'll be able to see this process happening via log output.